# Modular arithmetic using fractions

Tags: modulo

I'm stuck on this cryptography problem using multiplication of a whole number and a fraction mod 10.

Here is the equation:

```
7 * (4/11) mod 10 =?
```

I know I am supposed to convert this to an integer since the mod operator does not work with fractions, but I cannot figure this one out. Obviously,

```
7 * (4/11) = 28/11,
```

but I cannot get the mod 10 of a fraction. The instructor wants the exact answer, not a decimal. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first thing you need is to define what x mod 10 means if x is not an integer.   If `x` and `y` are integers, then one definition would be `x/y mod 10` is equal to `[x mod (10*y)]/y`   (which will be a rational value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 8

8 is the correct answer indeed.

`7*4/11 mod 10` means we're looking at `7*4*x mod 10` where x is the modular inverse of 11 modulo 10, which means that `11*x mod 10 = 1`.
This is true for `x=1` (`11*1 mod 10 = 1`)

So `7*4*x mod 10` becomes `7*4*1 mod 10` which is `28 mod 10 = 8`

Answer (score 5):

Have a look here: "[*Is it possible to do modulo of a fraction*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864568/is-it-possible-to-do-modulo-of-a-fraction)" on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

> One natural way to define the modular function is
>
> a (mod b) = a − b ⌊a / b⌋
>
> where ⌊⋅⌋ denotes the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). This is the approach used in the influential book [Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025) by Graham, Knuth, Patashnik.
>
> This will give you 1/2(mod3)=1/2.

To work through your problem, you have `a = 7 * (4/11) = 28/11`, and `b = 10`.

`a / b` = (28/11)/10 = 0.25454545...

`⌊a/b⌋` = 0

`b ⌊a/b⌋` = 0 * 0 = 0

`a - b ⌊a/b⌋` = 28/11 - 0 = 28/11

This means your answer is 28/11.

Wolfram Alpha [agrees with me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(7+*+(4%2F11))+mod+10) and gives `28/11` as the *exact* result. [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=(7+*+(4%2F11))+mod+10&oq=(7+*+(4%2F11))+mod+10) also agrees, but gives it as a decimal, 2.54545454.....

A fraction **is** an *exact* answer and not a decimal.

Comment: I got 28/11 as well, but my professor claims this is wrong.

Comment: What answer *does* your professor get, out of interest? Unless it's `2   6/11` (= 28/11 written as a whole number and a [proper fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Proper_and_improper_fractions)) I'm not sure what answer he could get.

Comment: according to the accepted answer, the professor wanted `(28 mod 10)/(11 mod 10)`

Answer (score 1):

I can speculate that the notation is wrong, and that the whole expression is supposed to be evaluated in mod 10 at each intermediate stage.  Since ( 11 mod 1 ) is 1, then answer is (7 * 4) mod 10 = 8.

Imagine a calculator with support only for the ones digit.

I'm not saying this is the right answer, I agree 28/11 is the right answer as given, but I am trying to get into the head of the professor. This is common in cryptography, where every calculation is performed mod 2 ^ 256 or so.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I appreciate the help. I'll post back with the exact answer the instructor wants.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the original question probably should have been written, as this has a different meaning.  [When the `(mod 10)` is written at the end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), it means that each term is evaluated with an implied `mod 10` operation.

[image: \sqrt{foo}]

The problem is a bit weird, as the modulo value of 10 is not general purpose, because it is not prime. For example, the following can not be evaluated because `1/2 mod 10` is not defined, because 2 and 10 are not coprime.

[image: \sqrt{foo}]

Answer (score 1):

So, here is the correct answer from the instructor. I have no idea how he came up with this:

```
    7  4/11 mod 10 = ((7  4) mod 10)(11−1 mod 10) mod 10
    = (28 mod 10)(1 mod 10) mod 10
    = (8)(1) mod 10
    = 8 mod 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python:

```
from fractions import Fraction
from math import fmod

print (fmod(Fraction(28, 11), 10))
```

The result will be 2.545454545454. So I guess 8 is wrong.

Comment: can you explain what you did and how you came to your solution