# Solving modulo in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, modulus, modulo

I'm having troubles solving modulo in c#. The example below

```
7^-1 modulo 26
```

when on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=570e7445d8bdb334c7128de82b81fc13) returns correct **15**. In **c#** when I tried direct:

```cs
1/7 % 26
```

it returns *unwanted* `0.142857142857143` instead of desired `15`.
But i'm not a master mathematician, so i'm probably missing something vital.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modular arithmetic using fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418693/modular-arithmetic-using-fractions)

Comment: @GSerg they don't really offer direct solution to this issue.

Comment: `they don't really offer direct solution` - [they do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32418836/11683). You just seem to want a simpler one.

Comment: `1/7 % 26` is the remainder when dividing 1/7 by 26 so obviously it must be 1/7. See the [result on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F7+mod+26)

Comment: Solution is called modular inversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are looking for *modular inversion*: in case of

```
7**-1 modulo 26 = x
```

or

```
1 / 7 modulo 26 = x
```

you actually want to find out an `x` such that

```
(x * 7) modulo 26 = 1
```

In our case `x == 15` since

```
 15 * 7 == 105 == 26 * 4 + 1
```

For *small* `modulo` values (like `26`) you can find the answer (`15`) with a help of *naive* `for` loop:

```
  int modulo = 26;
  int div = 7;
  int result = 0;
  
  for (int i = 1; i < modulo; ++i)
    if ((i * div) % modulo == 1) {
      result = i;

      break;
    }

  Console.Write(result);
```

In general case, you can obtain the `result` with a help of [Extended Euclid Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Often, when working with modulo arithmetics we face huge numbers, that's why let me show the code for `BigInteger`; if it's not your case you can turn `BigInteger` to good old `int`.

**Code:**

```
using System.Numerics;
...
private static (BigInteger LeftFactor,
                BigInteger RightFactor,
                BigInteger Gcd) Egcd(this BigInteger left, BigInteger right) {
  BigInteger leftFactor = 0;
  BigInteger rightFactor = 1;

  BigInteger u = 1;
  BigInteger v = 0;
  BigInteger gcd = 0;

  while (left != 0) {
    BigInteger q = right / left;
    BigInteger r = right % left;

    BigInteger m = leftFactor - u * q;
    BigInteger n = rightFactor - v * q;

    right = left;
    left = r;
    leftFactor = u;
    rightFactor = v;
    u = m;
    v = n;

    gcd = right;
  }

  return (LeftFactor: leftFactor,
          RightFactor: rightFactor,
          Gcd: gcd);
}
```

The inversion itself will be

```
private static BigInteger ModInversion(BigInteger value, BigInteger modulo) {
  var egcd = Egcd(value, modulo);

  if (egcd.Gcd != 1)
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid modulo", nameof(modulo));

  BigInteger result = egcd.LeftFactor;

  if (result < 0)
    result += modulo;

  return result % modulo;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
using System.Numerics;

...

BigInteger result = ModInversion(7, 26);

Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
15
```

Comment: I already found it and just forgot to say, but this is exactly what i have been looking for. Marking as solution.